# Python Dictionary: How to update dictionary value, base on key - using separate dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, replace, updates

I've got two dictionaries of unequal length, e.g.:

```
people = {"john" : "carpenter", "jill": "locksmith", "bob":"carpenter", "jane": "pilot", "dan": "locksmith"}

jobcode = {"carpenter": 1, "locksmith": 2, "pilot": 3}
```

What I'm wanting to do is replace the values in `people` with the `jobcode` value.
So youd end up with:
n

```
people = {"john": 1, "jill": 2, "bob": 1, "jane": 3, "dan":2}
```

I'd be happy to make another new `dict` that encapsulates this new data as well but so far the closest I think I've come is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538665/replace-values-in-python-dict)... I think...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with dict comprehension

```
{k: jobcode[v] for k, v in people.items()}
```

However you should be careful since it can raise `KeyError`.

Another way with default `jobcode` with `dict` [`.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
default_jobcode = 1000
final_dict = {k: jobcode.get(v, default_jobcode) for k, v in people.items()}
```

**UPDATE**

As [@Graipher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4042267/graipher) kindly noted, if `jobcode` dict is lack of key-value pair, you can leave item untouched as such:

```
final_dict = {k: jobcode.get(v, v) for k, v in people.items()}
```

Which is probably better solution that having default `jobcode`.

Comment: You could also leave keys that are not in `jobcode` untouched with `jobcode.get(v, v)`.

Comment: @Graipher it could be the case, however it would broke `str: int` dict convention(if such exist). But Thank you, i updated my answer!

Comment: True. On the other hand it allows multiple passes with jobcodes from multiple sources, if needed. It's good to know about both methods, one might need either in different situations.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats exactly what was happening. Because I wasnt using .get(v, v) I was getting a key error! All the code seemed to make sense to me! I hope this is helpful to someone else in the same situation!

Answer (score 2):

**Ty this:-**

```
people = {'john' : 'carpenter', 'jill': 'locksmith', 'bob':'carpenter', 'jane': 'pilot', 'dan': 'locksmith'}
jobcode = {'carpenter': 1, 'locksmith': 2, 'pilot': 3}
for i,j in people.items():
    if j in jobcode.keys():
        people[i] = jobcode[j]
print(people)
```