# Update dictionary keys inside a list based on another dictionary key value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which has nested dictionary inside it and also a dictionary with respective key pair values.
I am trying to map the key from dict2 to keys for the dictionary elements inside the list.

```
list = [{'name': 'Megan', 'Age': '28', 'occupation': 'yes', 'race': 'american', 'children': 'yes'}, {'name': 'Ryan', 'Age': '25', 'occupation': 'no', 'race': 'american', 'intern': 'yes'}]
```

The respective dictionary which holds the correct keys is

```
dict_map = {'occupation': 'service', 'intern': 'employee', 'race': 'ethnicity'}
```

I am new to python so far I am trying to go through stackoverflow pages to get an output tried few as well but not able to get the desired result so far.
The closet I got was with this [Python Dictionary: How to update dictionary value, base on key - using separate dictionary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108222/python-dictionary-how-to-update-dictionary-value-base-on-key-using-separate)

The final output should be:

```
 [{'name': 'Megan', 'Age': '28', 'service': 'yes', 'ethnicity': 'american', 'children': 'yes'}, {'name': 'Ryan', 'Age': '25', 'service': 'no', 'ethnicity': 'american', 'employee': 'yes'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

note that i renamed your list to `lst` (`list` is abuilt-in type that you should never overwrite!)

```
lst = [
    {
        "name": "Megan",
        "Age": "28",
        "occupation": "yes",
        "race": "american",
        "children": "yes",
    },
    {
        "name": "Ryan",
        "Age": "25",
        "occupation": "no",
        "race": "american",
        "intern": "yes",
    },
]


for dct in lst:
    for old_key, new_key in dict_map.items():
        if old_key not in dct:
            continue
        dct[new_key] = dct[old_key]
        del dct[old_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension with `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
lst = [{'name': 'Megan', 'Age': '28', 'occupation': 'yes', 'race': 'american', 'children': 'yes'}, {'name': 'Ryan', 'Age': '25', 'occupation': 'no', 'race': 'american', 'intern': 'yes'}]
dict_map = {'occupation': 'service', 'intern': 'employee', 'race': 'ethnicity'}
result = [{dict_map.get(k, k): v for k, v in i.items()} for i in lst]            
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Age': '28',
  'children': 'yes',
  'ethnicity': 'american',
  'name': 'Megan',
  'service': 'yes'},
 {'Age': '25',
  'employee': 'yes',
  'ethnicity': 'american',
  'name': 'Ryan',
  'service': 'no'}]
```